# Extending Laplace transform to multivariate cases?

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform, gaussian-integral

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a measurable $L^\infty$ function. Assume further that $f$ is not zero a.e. and $f(-x)=f(x)$ for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then, I wonder if we can conclude that there exists some $c \in (0,\infty)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)e^{-c\lVert x \rVert^2}d^nx \neq 0
\end{equation}
as an element of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

I asked a similar question before : [If $f(x) \neq 0$ on $[0,\infty)$, does there exists some $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$ such that $\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-\alpha x^2}dx \neq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794434/if-fx-neq-0-on-0-infty-does-there-exists-some-alpha-in-0-infty/4794439#4794439)

However, I cannot extend to multivariate cases based on the condition $f(-x)=f(x)$..

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I would imagine something like $x \mapsto \cos (\arg x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ would have zero integral for all $c>0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you perhaps answer the following question as well : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803498/if-f-neq-0-do-we-have-int-x-i-geq-0-fx-e-sum-i-1n-c-i-x-i2-d