# If $f \neq 0$, do we have $\int_{ x_i \geq 0} f(x) e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i^2} d^nx \neq 0$ for some $c \in (0,\infty)^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform, gaussian-integral

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a bounded measurable mapping. Next, define
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{R}^n_+ := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i=1,\cdots,n\}
\end{equation}

Now, assume further that $f(x) \neq 0$ for a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ of positive measure.

My question is now that:

is it true that
\begin{equation}
\int_{ \mathbb{R}^n_+} f(x) e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i^2} d^nx \neq 0
\end{equation}
as an element of $\mathbb{R}^m$ for some $c=(c_i) \in (0,\infty)^n$?

I think this is essentially an extension of my previous question [If $f(x) \neq 0$ on $[0,\infty)$, does there exists some $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$ such that $\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-\alpha x^2}dx \neq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794434/if-fx-neq-0-on-0-infty-does-there-exists-some-alpha-in-0-infty/4794439?noredirect=1#comment10194709_4794439) but seems trickier than expected..

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Apply previous result to $\int_{ \mathbb{R}^{n-1}_+} f(x) e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i^2} d(x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$  and so on.